# creating a monogame game without game1.cs class

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Though I have some understanding on the C# programming language, I'm still quite new to the monogame framework.

From all the monogame tutorials I've seen, all the games created make extensive use of the game1.cs class, a class pre-made for you upon creating a new monogame project. It seems that everything is done in the game1.cs class, drawing, logic, loading assets etc. I know from experience however that having too much of something in one class is not a good idea.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a monogame game without the game1.cs class, and if it is possible, I would like to know how to perform functions such as Draw() and Update() from a class outside of game1.cs.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can of course re-name the class to your preferences. Or split it into several parts or whatever. The only thing you hav to ensure is that there´s a valif application-antry-point (not sure, what this is in mono). From there you can reeference any other class.

Comment: "I'm still quite new to the monogame framework" That is the problem. Learn more and you will know what to do. Now you can do basic stuff in one class while learning. Later you will find out how to do it better. Also please read help in stackowerflow how to ask and what to ask, because you are also new here and your question is not of the kind we expect to see here. Good luck in learning.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I'll be sure to ask more specific questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the Game-class that comes with MonoGame is that you don't have to manually write a gameloop and keep track of the rendering on your platform.

I use the Game1.cs that comes with each newly generated project, only as a startingpoint from where my software starts services, like the debugger, a statemachine for the scene-flow or a renderdelegation. They are still separate classes but use the Update and Draw methods as roots for their own regular updates.

I'd suggest you to do two things: Read the chapter "Game Loop" in the book Game Programming Patterns ([link](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html)) and look at the class that Game1 inherits from ([link](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Game.cs)).